# Generics and inheritance - only supertypes needed in code

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I need to work with a generic class and its type argument in my client code.

```
public class Usable {
    ...
}


public interface User<T extends Usable> {
    public void use(T usable);
}


//client
public class UserDemo { 
    public void demo() {
        Usable usable = getUsable();    //returns Usable
        User<? extends Usable> user = getUser();    //returns User<? extends Usable>

        user.use(usable); //compilation error.
    }

    public Usable getUsable() {
        ....
    }

    public User<? extends Usable> getUser() {
        ....
    }
}
```

The compilation error is that the expected type is `<? extends Usable>` but the passed type is `Usable`. How do I get around this problem? The constraints are:

1. The client code(`UserDemo`) can only work on `User` and `Usable` (not their subtypes).
2. User can only work on objects whose types are subtypes of `Usable`.

Comment: What is the signature of `getUsable`? Also you use it twice so I guess there is a typo. Also provide the signature of the other method.

Comment: There are quite a few typos in this code. Please clean it up.

Comment: Updated the code with the definitions of getUser() and getUsable() and corrected typos.

Answer (score 3):

This can't work:

- `user.use(usable);` expects the T of `User<T extends Usable>`, which can be `Usable` or a subclass of `Usable`
- `usable` is a `Usable`
- `getUser()` returns a `? extends Usable`

So you could imagine a scenario where:

- `getUser` returns a `SubUsable`, a subclass of `Usable`
- meaning that `user.use()` expects a `SubUsable` and can't accept the Usable you are trying to pass

If you change the signature of `getUser` to return a `Usable`, it will work:

```
public void demo() {
    Usable usable = getUsable();
    User<Usable> user = getUser();
    user.use(usable);
}

public Usable getUsable() { return null; }

public User<Usable> getUser() { return null; }
```

Comment: Yes, but the method getUser() has to have a return type which is an implementation of  User<a class which is a subtype of Usable>.

Comment: @pflz In which case it can return a `user` which is a `User<SubUsable>` and you can't pass your `Usable usable` to a `User<SubUsable>`...

Comment: But my client code should be agnostic of SubUsable. It only knows that the type parameter subtypes Usable.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I only need to work with User whose type parameter can be any subtype of Usable.

Comment: @pflz What I'm saying is that your `Usable usable` can only be used by a `User<Usable>`. So something in your design has to be relaxed. An alternative would be change the signature of getUser to: `public <T extends Usable> User<T> getUser()` and keep `User<Usable> user = getUser();`.